# coinbase sdk unable to get response

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, coinbase-api, wallet

I am using this three methods to update coinbase but i am not getting response in any of them, please help me, here is my code:

```
[primaryAccount requestAmount:@"0.001" amountCurrencyISO:@"BTC" from:@"1EbKfp6W6K2rtubuVEMDoaytWMsY4wtNHM" notes:@"Test amount" completion:^(CoinbaseTransaction *tarnsation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@",tarnsation);
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

}];


[primaryAccount sendAmount:@"0.001" to:@"1EbKfp6W6K2XgubwwEMDoaytWMsY4wtNHM" completion:^(CoinbaseTransaction *tarnsation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",tarnsation);
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];

[primaryAccount transferAmount:@"0.001" to:@"1EbKfp6W6K2XgubuVEMDo22tWMsY4wtNHM" completion:^(CoinbaseTransaction *tarnsation, NSError *error)
                 {                

    NSLog(@"%@",tarnsation);
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
```

Comment: Have you tried contacting them? I don't think this belongs on StackOverflow as we have no way of answering this

Comment: Also this is a strange number of upvotes and favorites for the number of views this question has..